# on reading tiff file using skimage

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, tiff, scikit-image

I am using the following code to read a set of tiff files from a folder

```
from PIL import image
from skimage import io
io.use_plugin('pil')
images = os.listdir(train_data_path)
for image_name in images:
    img = io.imread(os.path.join(train_data_path, image_name))
```

When running the above code, most of the files were reading smoothly. But I found the program will generate some warning message for some specific file

```
/devl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/scikit_image-0.12.3-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/skimage/external/tifffile/tifffile.py:1794: RuntimeWarning: py_decodelzw encountered unexpected end of stream                                  
strip = decompress(strip)
```

When opening that file, I cannot see any explicit difference with others. What can the reason underlying this?

Comment: Same problem here...

Comment: I have encountered the same issue, only my image definitely looked different (and incorrect) compared with the correctly-opened image.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and resolved it by explicitly setting the plugin in the call to imread:

```
img = imread(img_path, plugin='pil')
```

According to the skimage.io.imread [docs](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html):

> plugin : str, optional Plugin to load. Defaults to None, in which case
>   the first matching plugin is used.

So, in may case, imread was finding the Tifffile plugin, which was producing the error (for some reason), whereas PIL reads the files correctly. I do not know the source of the Tifffile error.