# Skimage imread TiffFileError: not a TIFF file

Tags: python, tiff, scikit-image

I saved three outputs from a model (all numpy arrays) using

```
skimage.io.imsave('file_path\\name.tif')
```

All look to be saved correctly as tif files.
I open with:

```
skimage.io.imread(file_path)
```

two open fine, but the third produces

```
TiffFileError: not a TIFF file
```

I've tried the solution at this link but that produces the following error
[on reading tiff file using skimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159603/on-reading-tiff-file-using-skimage)

```
UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file
```

Comment: Have you tried to change `skimage.io.imsave('file_path\\name.tif')` to `skimage.io.imsave('file_path\\name.tiff')` ? Cause `.tif` and `.tiff` are different files.

Comment: I've resaved them and it is working fine again. So 5/6 of the files I've tried have worked fine with the .tif ending. The process has not been changed and the original problem for that one file persists. I'll leave this open in case someone can shed some light on why this has occured.